# How make multi word entities a single word?

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition

I have a pandas column with multiple word entities. I want to make the entities labeled as PERSON a single word. My input looks like this:

```
    Text
 Vote for Donald Trump
 Vote for Barack Obama
 Vote for Bernie Sanders
 Move to another location
 Support LaVaughn Robinson
 Support Michelle LaVaughn Robinson
 Support Sanders
```

I need my output to look like this:

```
   Text
Vote for Donald_Trump
Vote for Barack_Obama
Vote for Bernie_Sanders
Move to another location
Support LaVaughn_Robinson
Support Michelle_LaVaughn_Robinson
Support Sanders
```

My first though was to use Spacy NER, return the PERSON and later combined the words returned, but I'm getting words that are not NER.  Can I do it using BILOU? Is there any other way to do it?

Updated question

I have a new dataset that have 2 columns. Spacy NER seems to performe best, but it only identifies the NER(persons) on the column complete_text. When I run it on the column incomplete_text, it cannot identify the NER(persons). Is there a way to map the person identify on the column complete_text and matched  it with the person on column incomplete_text. I'm sorry if this sounds confusing. This is how my dataset looks like:

```
complete_text                             incomplete_text                            
everyone to vote for Marine Le Pen     vote for Marine Le Pen
```

When I use spacy to get the person on both the complete_text column and the incomplete_text column, It only returns the person on the complete_text not on the incomplete_text. I want  want to match the person identified on the complete_text column with the person on the incomplete_text column and return the person identified as a single word.

```
complete_text                           spacy_complete_text_person   incomplete_text                spacy_incomplete_text__person      result                                         
everyone to vote for Marine Le Pen     [Marine Le Pen]                 vote for Marine Le Pen                  []                      vote for Marine_Le_Pen
```

Comment: Do you have always a first and a last name?

Comment: No, I also have  2 last names (LaVaughn Robinson) or a first name and 2 last names (Michel LaVaughn Robinson). Thank you very much for helping me with this.

Comment: But you have at least 2 or 3 consecutive names? Not 1?

Comment: Usually! But I do have cases in which I only have one word like Obama.

Comment: Do you already try BERT?

Comment: No, I tried to use flair but I couldn’t find a way to return words labeled as PER only instead of all labels.

Comment: I also tried NLTK but it was far less accurate than Spacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BERT` model from [`dslim/bert-base-NER`](https://huggingface.co/dslim/bert-base-NER) using [`transformers`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers):

```
# Python env: pip install transformers
# Anaconda env: conda install transformers
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification
from transformers import pipeline

def process_person(txt):
    # Currently not optimized for Pandas
    l = nlp(txt)
    for d in l:
        if d['entity_group'] == 'PER':
            s = d['start']
            e = d['end']
            txt = txt[:s] + txt[s:e+1].replace(' ', '_') + txt[e:]
    return txt

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-large-NER")
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-large-NER")

nlp = pipeline("ner", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, aggregation_strategy='max')
df['Text2'] = df['Text'].apply(process_person)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                 Text                               Text2
0               Vote for Donald Trump               Vote for Donald_Trump
1               Vote for Barack Obama               Vote for Barack_Obama
2             Vote for Bernie Sanders             Vote for Bernie_Sanders
3            Move to another location            Move to another location
4           Support LaVaughn Robinson           Support LaVaughn_Robinson
5  Support Michelle LaVaughn Robinson  Support Michelle_LaVaughn_Robinson
6                     Support Sanders                     Support Sanders
7                           RT Please                           RT Please
8                            STOP luc                            STOP luc
9                           Kick Some                           Kick Some
```

Comment: Both answers work great. I was using en_core_web_sm instead of en_core_web_trf. I greatly appreciate you taking the time to reply.

Comment: Hi, do you offer any tutoring?

Comment: No, sorry I don't have the skills to teach anything but I can answer to your questions :)

Comment: I updated my question, do you think you can help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf`

Given:

```
                                 Text
0               Vote for Donald Trump
1               Vote for Barack Obama
2             Vote for Bernie Sanders
3            Move to another location
4           Support LaVaughn Robinson
5  Support Michelle LaVaughn Robinson
6                     Support Sanders
7                  Vote for RT Please
8                            STOP luc
9                   Support Kick Some
```

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")

df.Text = df.Text.apply(nlp)

print(df.Text.apply(lambda x: x.ents))
print(df.Text.apply(lambda t: [x.label_ for x in t.ents]))
```

Output:

```
0                   ((Donald, Trump),)
1                   ((Barack, Obama),)
2                 ((Bernie, Sanders),)
3                                   ()
4              ((LaVaughn, Robinson),)
5    ((Michelle, LaVaughn, Robinson),)
6                         ((Sanders),)
7                                   ()
8                                   ()
9                                   ()

0    [PERSON]
1    [PERSON]
2    [PERSON]
3          []
4    [PERSON]
5    [PERSON]
6    [PERSON]
7          []
8          []
9          []
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

Seems to be finding things fairly well for me~

Comment: Yes, Spacy does find things pretty well, but it's also returning words as PERSON that are not clearly a PERSON. For instance, "RT Please", "STOP luc", "Kick Some". The idea is to turn those multi word entities a single word by using _ . Spacy is returning verbs as PERSON also.

Comment: @CPDatascience Which training set are you using? I don't seem to have the same issue with those phrases as you using `en_core_web_trf`...

Comment: You’re absolutely right. Big mistake… I was using en_core_web_sm. It works perfectly. Thank you very much for making that observation.